# Table statistics on database

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, oracle-11g

Is there any way that I could find how many tables has statistics on them,and how many tables which doesn't have statistics on them.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to ensure all tables in the database has stats on them.there are 2k tables  should I check manually whether this table exists in dba_tab_stats_history view.

Comment: Stats are gathered automatically when data has been changed more then 10% or some specific object doesn't have statistics at all(new object, table, etc.).
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/stats.htm
Unless you are experiencing some performance issues you don't have to do anything manually.

Comment: how about checking the global_stats column in dba_tables.if global_stats column set to NO(for non partitioned table) ,can we conclude the table has no statistics.

Answer (score 1):

All the information regarding statistics gathered with dbms_stats can be found on dba_tab_stats_history.

Ref.: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2103.htm#BGBBBGCC